# How to avoid enumeration of object files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Well, project has:

-include directory /* for header files */

-src dir. /* for source code */

-build dir. /* for object and executable files */

Makefile:

```
  1 BUILD_DIR   = $(CURRENT_DIR)/build
  2 INCLUDE_DIR = $(CURRENT_DIR)/include
  3 SRC_DIR     = $(CURRENT_DIR)/src
  4
  5 CC = gcc
  6 CFLAGS = -Wall -g -I
  7
  8 $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDE_DIR)/%.h
  9     @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -c $< -o $@
 10
 11 SRC_FILES   =   $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
 12 HEADER_FILES=   $(wildcard $(INCLUDE_DIR)/*.h)
 13
 14
 15 OBJECT_FILES=   $(BUILD_DIR)/module_1.o        \
 16                 $(BUILD_DIR)/module_2.o        \
 17                 $(BUILD_DIR)/module_3.o
 18 
 19
 20 prog: $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(OBJECT_FILES)
 21     @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $^ -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$@
```

How to avoid enumeration of object files, smth like:

```
OBJECT_FILES = $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o)
```

but this line produce "undefined reference" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `$(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o)` because those files don't exist when the makefile is read in: they are built by the makefile.  So this will be empty when you start to build.

Generally what people do is convert the list of source files into object files, since that's what the compiler does.  So:

```
OBJECT_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
```